# Octave's start:step:end loop

Tags: octave

I cannot understand how

```
input = [];
for i = 1:8
    input(i) = sin( (2*pi) * 1000 * ((i-1)*ts) ) +  (0.5*sin( (2*pi) * 2000 * ((i-1)*ts) + 3*pi/4 ));
endfor
```

Is the same as

```
i = 0 : (1/8000) : (1/1000);
input = sin( 2*pi*1000*i ) +  0.5*sin( 2*pi*2000*i + 3*pi/4 );
```

How can a for loop where it goes from 0 to 8, be the same as when i goes from 0 to 1/1000 in steps of 1/8000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `ts = 1/8000` and you actually mean `for i = 1:9` ...otherwise you'll end up with result vectors that aren't the same size...

Maybe it would help to think of 1/8000 as one-eighth of 1/1000. That way each step brings you one-eighth of the way from 0 to 1/1000.

Unless there's something about your question that I'm missing?

Comment: no that is pretty much it. hard to get the 'think in vectors' concept.